# How to restrict focus in textbox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a dialog with few controls. There is a `TextBox` named *txtControl* and two `Buttons` *Accept* and *Cancel*. I want that once the focus is in *txtControl*, the focus should not go away, until I click on *Accept* or *Cancel* button.

If I try to click on any other control without clicking on *Accept* or *Cancel* button, then focus should remains in *txtControl*. Also I don't want to disable or gray out other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an attached property that looked for the textbox losing Keyboad focus and just force focus back in to the textbox again.

The attached property would be something like this.

```
  public class TextBoxExtras : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetRetainsFocus(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(RetainsFocusProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRetainsFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(RetainsFocusProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RetainsFocusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RetainsFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxExtras), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
                {
                    TextBox textBox = s as TextBox;
                    if (textBox != null)
                    {
                        if (!(bool)e.NewValue && (bool)e.OldValue)
                            textBox.LostKeyboardFocus -= textBox_LostKeyboardFocus;
                        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                        {
                            textBox.LostKeyboardFocus += textBox_LostKeyboardFocus;
                            textBox.Unloaded += textBox_Unloaded;
                        }
                    }
                })));

        static void textBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null )
                if (textBox.Focusable)
                    textBox.Focus();
        }

        static void textBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.LostKeyboardFocus -= textBox_LostKeyboardFocus;
                textBox.Unloaded -= textBox_Unloaded;
            }
        }
    }
```

And use it in XAML like this, the first textbox is the one that will "retain focus"

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Background="Black"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox local:TextBoxExtras.RetainsFocus="True" Margin="10,10,387,283"/>        
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,37,0,260" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Accept" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might handle OnPreviewMouseDown in the root, whenever focus is on txtControl, and the mouse is not over txtControl, Accept or Cancel;

```
void mainWindow_previewMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArg e)
{

     if (txtControl.IsFocusWithin)         
     {
          if (txtControl.IsMouseOver == false ||
             accept.IsMouseOver ==false ||
             cancel.IsMouseOver ==false)
          {
              e.Handle = true;
          }
      }
}
```

and you might also hadle PreviewKeyDown to see if Tab is Pressed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of restriction is not a good idea.

How will your app be used by someone who can't use a mouse and uses the tab key to move between controls?

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the [PreviewLostKeyboardFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewlostkeyboardfocus.aspx) at root level.

In xaml

```
<Window ... PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="Win_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus">
```

In C#

```
private void Win_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // change focus behavior only when txtControl 
                          // is the element losing focus
        if (e.OldFocus != txtControl)
            return;

                          // if new element with focus is not Accept and is not Cancel, then disable the focus change
        if (e.NewFocus != Accept && e.NewFocus != Cancel)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This won't prevent the user from setting the focus to the buttons and then immediately moving on. "How can they do that??!!" I hear you ask... with the Tab key.

Comment: I agree. On the other hand the question is about the case when the textbox is focused. If the textbox is focused and then the user press the Tab key, the focus on the textbox is lost only if the new focused element is either Accept or Cancel button (depending on TabIndex).